Meaning of within-class Covariance in Linear Discriminant Analysis Dimensionality Reduction
In section 4.3.3 of Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman the authors listed a procedure to reduce the dimensions of an input matrix $\mathbf{X}$, first using Linear Discriminant Analysis and then using Principal Component Analysis:

Compute the $K\times p$ matrix of class centroids $\mathbf{M}$ and the common covariance matrix $\mathbf{W}$ (the within-class covariance);
Compute $\mathbf{M}^* = \mathbf{MW}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ using the spectral decomposition of $\mathbf{W}$;
Compute $\mathbf{B}^*$, the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{M}^*$ and its spectral decomposition $\mathbf{B}^* = \mathbf{V}^*\mathbf{D}_B{\mathbf{V}^*}^T$.

This gives the l-th discriminant variable $Z_l = v_l^TX$ with corresponding discriminant direction $v_l=\mathbf{W}^{-\frac{1}{2}}v_l^*$.
My understanding of the procedure is that $\mathbf{X}$ is first projected onto the subspace created by the centroids (which does not affect LDA results), and the subspace undergoes Principle Component Analysis to further shrink its dimensions. I'm confused by how my understanding aligns with the matrix operations above, particularly the effects of $\mathbf{W}$.
